# Find the FPS to take screenshots with varying video FPS?

Tags: html, html5-video, render, video-processing, frame-rate

I am building a video rendering engine and am stuck on a problem. I would like to determine the rate at which to take the screenshots.

Currently, I am setting the rate to be 25 fps. From that, I can determine the total screenshots, as an example, a 10-second video would be 250 screenshots.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 250; i++ {
  //... i / 25 fps is what I set the HTML 5 video to be
  //... this means every 0.04s or 40ms a screenshot is taken
}
```

The problem is that in my editor a user may combine a 25 fps video with a 30 fps video. I have found the 30 fps video will at times be choppy because the natual rate would be `i / 30` which means it needs a screenshot every 0.033s or 33ms.

I am trying to come up with ways to combat this from being an issue. I would like to inform myself more around solving this problem.

As for solutions with my existing knowledge I can only think of two.

- make sure every video that gets added to the editor gets re-encoded with 25fps, this could still cause issues and be problematic, since removing frames could cause jank, and adding frames is impossible.
- have a variable frame rate while taking the screenshots so that when the video in view is 30fps I can change the rate of the screenshot mechanism. This poses problems when layers on top use an animation frame rate of 25 fps, or if it's next to a video side by side with a frame rate of 25.

Both solutions I can think of arent the best. So I would like to ask the folks who understand this problem the most and would like to share some of that knowledge.

Lastly, it seems the browser does a good job of handling this which tells me it's possible. Here is a screen recording of the app https://share.getcloudapp.com/KouwpkwE the first run was a bit sluggish but the second one showcases the video in the background using a frame rate of 30, then the lottie animation on top using a frame rate of 25.

When trying to capture this frame by frame at a fixed 25 I run into issues. Any techniques to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: If this was my problem... First, using a video editor, I would put two "time-code" videos side by side (one at 25 and the other is 30 FPS) and then render out a 25 FPS video. Next I would check the output frame-by-frame in some media player to see how the 30 FPS time-code frame numbers changed in comparison to the 25 FPS.

Comment: There’s a limitation with that though. If you have layers and there are some key frame animations between clips.